# Can I use a function in place of a variable?

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I'm curious if PHP can handle code like this, or if I'm using the wrong syntax:

```
$someString = implode(', ', function(){
    return array('a', 'b', 'c');
});
```

With the desired output being `a, b, c`.

I'm using PHP version 5.3.3.

Comment: Nope: http://3v4l.org/7Ojrr

Comment: Note that PHP does have support for closures in certain parameters. But they can't be used everywhere (as is the same in pretty much any language that accepts closures).

Comment: @John Conde, I should have mentioned that I knew the code I pasted was invalid.  I was hoping I was missing the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `implode()` takes an array, so you have to immediately execute the closure:

```
$someString = implode(', ', call_user_func(function(){
    return array('a', 'b', 'c');
}));
```

It would arguably be nicer to have this:

```
$someString = implode(', ', function(){
    return array('a', 'b', 'c');
}());
```

But that causes a parse error.

Another acceptable way:

```
$myGenerator = function(){
    return array('a', 'b', 'c');
};

$someString = implode(', ', $myGenerator());
```